# Run program.cs file of console application in Azure Function?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have a console application which I want to convert to an Azure Function Timer Trigger app which will run every hour after some data processing and uploads are done. The data processing and uploads are being done via classes which are injected in the program.cs file of the console application. Somewhere in the classes I have a task.delay by 1hour where it will query new data after the data has been queried and uploaded for the first time. So, I copied the entire code of the console application with its packages to the Azure Function Timer trigger app. What I am trying to do is to run the program.cs file of the console application first in the azure function app in order to do its job (data processing, querying data, uploading data to azure...). and then initiate the timer trigger. Is that doable ? What line of code can I add in the run method of the azure function app to execute the program.cs file first and then initiate the trigger. You can find here the startup code of the azure function time trigger app.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ExportServiceFunctionApp
{
    public static class ExportServiceFunctionApp
    {
        [FunctionName("ExportServiceFunctionApp")]

        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 */1 * * * ")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Aboudi and welcome to the Stackoverflow! Can you please edit your question and add the code there instead of providing a picture? This will make it easier for us to quickly edit and provide an answer.

Comment: @JustShadow I edited my question. Thank you. Just regarding your question. Why should I use the httptrigger. How will it know how to execute the program.cs file because the main method is not mentioned in the code. Note that I am still running it locally. How can I call the main method in this http trigger. It cannot be called by itself

Comment: Azure functions can't be called by themselves. They are waiting for a trigger. And there are different triggers for that. In case of using HttpTrigger the Azure function will expose a regular endpoint so you can call them via regular http GET/POST/.. calls.
Regarding the main method, move the code of your main method of the console app to the "Run" method here. And then you can use the solutions mentioned in the answers below.

Comment: @JustShadow Can I only use the time trigger without using httptrigger. So what I did is that I added the code of the main method inside the run method of the Azure Function. When I pressed F5 it started working however it gave me an exception related to application insights. But let us just ignore the exception, that actually worked without httptrigger ?

Comment: Sure you can use just timertrigger, but in that case after hitting F5, you'll need to wait for the appropriate time that you've mentioned in the code ("0 0 */1 * * *"). It won't be triggered as soon as you hit the F5

Comment: @JustShadow and how can I make it possible so that the main method runs first and then the time trigger again recursively. So once the main method gets the data the first time, the timertrigger will wait until 1hour and then after the hour has passed the main method should do its job again. Is it done via solution 2 that you provided. Or is there another way ? Because I was thinking if I want to deploy it on azure will it do the job by itself because locally I will have to copy the localhost and paste it everytime in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few solutions to achieve this.

**Solution 1. Temporarily replace the timer trigger with http trigger**

While debugging the app we just comment the first line of the original `Run` function and add an http trigger instead like this:

```
public static async Task Run([HttpTrigger] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
// public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
   // YOUR REGULAR CODE HERE
}
```

Then when running the app you'll see an endpoint like this:

[image]

Just open the endpoint in browser (or postman) and the function will get called.

And right **before** pushing the code to the repo, just bring back the original `Run` function and remove the http trigger one.

**Solution 2: Add another http trigger that calls the timer function**
Add the following function to your app to expose an http trigger.

```
        [FunctionName("Test")]
        public static async Task Test([HttpTrigger] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            Run(null, log);
        }
```

The function basically calls the `Run` function.
So when you run the app, again you'll get an endpoint from the console that can be used from the browser to trigger the function.
The url will look like this:
`http://localhost:7071/api/Test`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me clarify my question. I have in the solution explorer my Function App. Inside of it I copied all the code for the console application. The console application runs from the program.cs file. Somewhere in the code I tell the program to await for 1hour and then startover again. So what I need first is to run the program.cs file in the azure function. My question here is how can I let it run before the trigger. What code should I add to call it and as a final step I should trigger the schedule

Comment: You can add the code mentioned in "Solution 2" to your code, and then after running the app, open the following in your browser to trigger the function `http://localhost:7071/api/Test`

Comment: How does this timer trigger works. You mentioned that if the timertrigger was set to 1hour and I press f5 it will start after 1hour. In my case, I want the Main method to run for a first time once it finishes its job the timer trigger will make a delay for 1hour and after that hour has passed the Main method should start again. I want it to be recursive as if it never ends. Example: First things first main method starts then timer trigger delays for 1hour then main method starts again then timer trigger delays for 1hour etc (never stops) since it will be deployed on azure...

Comment: Unfortunately Azure doesn't provide such functionality to automatically run the code as soon as you hit F5 when developing locally. You have to use the triggers, but none of them provides that option.

Answer (score 0):

Azure functions is event driven in nature. If function trigger means the event handled.

Run method of function means that function has triggered and its entry point for it.

If you want any processing or code execution before it you may need to write one more function and perform the steps and then trigger another function of either timer trigger or ant different type.

Comment: What kind of function should I use before the timer trigger in order to run the program.cs file ? The program.cs file contains all the information to retrieve the data from a database query it and upload to azure. My question here is how can I do this ? How can I first run the program.cs file in azure function and then call the timer trigger. What line of code should I add ?